# Software sources not found 12.10

Tags: apt

When I go to click on a program, there's no 'download' or 'install' or anything, just 'more info' and when I click on it, I get this:

**NOT FOUND**

```
"There isn’t a software package called “<insert program name here>” in your current software sources."
```

For the longest time Flash wouldn't install into I got around it some how.

Comment: You should be able to install Flash by doing `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`.